# memory issue while using neo4j embedded

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I am facing an outOfMemory exception in below method. Could anyone please help?

This graph as 7073455 Nodes and 36549084 relations I am running this program with these parameters:
-Xmx3072M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Code:

```
public Iterable<Node> calculatePa(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) throws Exception {


float pa = 0.0f;
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx(); 
Iterable<Node> allNodes = getAllTypeNodes(graphDb, TERM_NODE);
int counter =0;
HashMap<String, String> starNodemap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(TERM_STAR_NODE_FILE_PATH);
Iterable<Relationship> pVRels;
Iterable<Relationship> removeRels;
Iterable<Relationship> pVRels2;
Node termNode;
Iterator<Node> termItr = allNodes.iterator();
while(termItr.hasNext()){
    termNode = termItr.next();
    int sumPV = 0,starNodeCounter = 0;
    pVRels = termNode.getRelationships( Direction.OUTGOING, RelTypes.PV);
    counter++;
    for (Relationship pvRel : pVRels){              
         sumPV +=Integer.parseInt(pvRel.getProperty(PV).toString());
         starNodeCounter++;

     }

    // to stop executing the rest of the code for this node
     if(starNodeCounter > STAR_NODE_TERM_THRESHOLD){

         if(isDebug){
             pw.println(termNode.getProperty(TERM).toString()+ PIPE    +String.valueOf(starNodeCounter));
             pw.flush();
         }
         removeRels = termNode.getRelationships(RelTypes.PV, Direction.OUTGOING );
         for (Relationship r : removeRels){
         r.delete();
     }
     termNode.delete();

     continue;
}
termNode.setProperty(SUM, sumPV);
pVRels2 = termNode.getRelationships( Direction.OUTGOING, RelTypes.PV);          
for (Relationship pvRel : pVRels2 ){
    pa = Integer.parseInt(pvRel.getProperty(PV).toString())/(float)sumPV;
    pvRel.setProperty(Pa, pa);
}

if(counter == COMMIT_SIZE){
    LOGGER.info("Calculated Pa for :::"+counter+"::: at ::"+(new Date()));
    LOGGER.info(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/(1024*1024)+"::: is the free memory before");
     tx.success();
     tx.close();
     tx = graphDb.beginTx();    
     LOGGER.info(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/(1024*1024)+"::: is the free memory after");
     counter =0;
}
}
if(counter!=0){
     tx.success();
}       
pw.close();
tx.close(); 

return allNodes;
}

public  Iterable<Node> getAllTypeNodes(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb , String type)    {           
Iterable<Node> allNodes = null; 
try( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() ){  
allNodes = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label(type));
//              long n_allNodes = IteratorUtil.count(allNodes);             
//  LOGGER.info("Count of "+type+"s -->"+n_allNodes);                           
tx.success();
}       
return allNodes;        
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can split up your code into smaller methods that are easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What percentage of your graph is pulled in by `getAllTypeNodes` ?

Can you share the OOM exception?

What is your COMMIT_SIZE?

Should be something around 10k to 50k (but you have to increment it for the rels too, otherwise you might end up with a commit-size of x but you actually have `x * (number of rels)` elements in your transaction.

Comment: getAllTypeNOdes method returns me around 6M nodes out of total 7M nodes and I have tried commit sizes of 10k, 50K, 100K. It failed every time. I am running it again and will post the exact stacktrace of the exception soon.